# Can someone please explain why it's giving me this error: AttributeError: 'pygame.Surface' object has no attribute 'clicked'

Tags: python, pygame

```
import pygame

class Piece():
    def __init__(self,pos,image,clicked):
        self.pos = pos
        self.image = image
        self.clicked = clicked
b_bi = pygame.image.load("Chess_bdt45.svg.png")
w_bi = pygame.image.load("Chess_blt45.svg.png")
b_k = pygame.image.load("Chess_kdt45.svg.png")
w_k = pygame.image.load("Chess_klt45.svg.png")
b_kn = pygame.image.load("Chess_ndt45.svg.png")
w_kn = pygame.image.load("Chess_nlt45.svg.png")
b_p = pygame.image.load("Chess_pdt45.svg.png")
w_p = pygame.image.load("Chess_plt45.svg.png")
b_q = pygame.image.load("Chess_qdt45.svg.png")
w_q = pygame.image.load("Chess_qlt45.svg.png")
b_r = pygame.image.load("Chess_rdt45.svg.png")
w_r = pygame.image.load("Chess_rlt45.svg.png")

b_r1= Piece((0,0),b_r,False)
b_kn1= Piece((1,0),b_kn,False)
b_bi1= Piece((2,0),b_bi,False)
b_q= Piece((4,0),b_q,False)
b_k= Piece((3,0),b_k,False)
b_bi2= Piece((5,0),b_bi,False)
b_kn2= Piece((6,0),b_kn,False)
b_r2= Piece((7,0),b_p,False)
b_p1= Piece((0,1),b_p,False)
b_p2= Piece((1,1),b_p,False)
b_p3= Piece((2,1),b_p,False)
b_p4= Piece((3,1),b_p,False)
b_p5= Piece((4,1),b_p,False)
b_p6= Piece((5,1),b_p,False)
b_p7= Piece((6,1),b_p,False)
b_p8= Piece((7,1),b_p,False)

w_r1= Piece((0,7),w_r,False)
w_kn1= Piece((1,7),w_kn,False)
w_bi1= Piece((2,7),w_bi,False)
w_q= Piece((3,7),w_q,False)
w_k= Piece((4,7),w_k,False)
w_bi2= Piece((5,7),w_bi,False)
w_kn2= Piece((6,7),w_kn,False)
w_r2= Piece((7,7),w_r,False)
w_p1= Piece((8,6),w_r,False)
w_p2= Piece((1,6),w_r,False)
w_p3= Piece((2,6),w_r,False)
w_p4= Piece((3,6),w_r,False)
w_p5= Piece((4,6),w_r,False)
w_p6= Piece((5,6),w_r,False)
w_p7= Piece((6,6),w_r,False)
w_p8= Piece((7,6),w_r,False)

vector = []
vector.append(b_r1)
vector.append(b_kn1)
vector.append(b_bi1)
vector.append(b_q)
vector.append(b_k)
vector.append(b_bi2)
vector.append(b_kn2)
vector.append(b_r2)
vector.append(w_r1)
vector.append(w_kn1)
vector.append(w_bi1)
vector.append(w_k)
vector.append(w_q)
vector.append(w_bi2)
vector.append(w_kn2)
vector.append(w_r2)

b_p = pygame.transform.scale(b_p,(100,100))
w_p = pygame.transform.scale(w_p,(100,100))

for i in range(len(vector)):
    vector[i] = pygame.transform.scale(vector[i].image, (100, 100))

def draw_pieces(screen):
    for Piece in vector:
        screen.blit(Piece.image, (Piece.pos[0] * 100, Piece.pos[1] * 100))
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\hsvdg\PycharmProjects\chessapp\pieces.py", line 85, in draw_pieces
screen.blit(Piece.image, (Piece.pos[0] * 100, Piece.pos[1] * 100))
AttributeError: 'pygame.Surface' object has no attribute 'image'

I have created the instances of the Piece Object and added them to the vector "vector", yet it still gives me this error. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs the function `pygame.transform.scale` returns a `Surface` object. Take a look here: https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.scale

In those lines you assign to each vector element the output of that function:

```py
for i in range(len(vector)):
    vector[i] = pygame.transform.scale(vector[i].image, (100, 100))
```

and thus you do NOT have your `Piece` objects in the vector, but the `Surface` objects returned from that call and they indeed do NOT have the `image` attribute.

Also `Piece` is a bad name in the for loop (this one):

```py
def draw_pieces(screen):
    for Piece in vector:
        screen.blit(Piece.image, (Piece.pos[0] * 100, Piece.pos[1] * 100))
```

It should be e.g. `piece`:

```py
def draw_pieces(screen):
    for piece in vector:
        screen.blit(piece.image, (piece.pos[0] * 100, piece.pos[1] * 100))
```

The `Piece` is shadowing the name of the class you defined above. If you fix the issue I mentioned above (with the faulty vector assignment / transformation) it will work, but it's still a bad practice to name it like that, it's confusing.